# Problem with Amazon Linux 1 + PHP FPM 5.6 + Composer 2 + OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips

Tags: php, openssl, composer-php, php-5.6, amazon-linux

I am having problems running the Composer 2 in an Amazon Linux 1 EC2 with OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips.

When I try to run `php composer.phar update` I get:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires linked library lib-openssl * but it has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to load the extension providing it.
  Problem 2
    - Root composer.json requires minishlink/web-push 1.4.3 -> satisfiable by minishlink/web-push[v1.4.3].
    - minishlink/web-push v1.4.3 requires lib-openssl * -> it has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to load the extension providing it.
```

Asking to PHP about the OpenSSL extension with `php -i | grep -i openssl` I can see it is installed

```
SSL Version => OpenSSL/1.0.2k
openssl
OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
Openssl default config => /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf
openssl.cafile => no value => no value
openssl.capath => no value => no value
Native OpenSSL support => enabled
```

While running `php composer.phar show -p | grep -i openssl`

```
ext-openssl                0          The openssl PHP extension (actual version: )
lib-curl-openssl           1.0.2.11   curl OpenSSL version (1.0.2.11)
lib-openssl-fips           1.0.2.11   OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
```

It seems that Composer 2 is not getting **lib-openssl**, but instead it gets **lib-openssl-fips** causing a dependency problem.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Why do you run `composer update`  on any remote system?

Comment: @NicoHaase: Commonly this is a build system in AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run `composer update` on the target platform and you know that `lib-openssl-fips` satisfies the `lib-openssl` requirement of `minishlink/web-push` but Composer is unaware, you can help Composer by telling it that the library (a *platform package*) exists.

This works by using the `--ignore-platform-req` option with the argument of the undetected library:

```
php composer.phar update --ignore-platform-req lib-openssl
```

Composer then ignores this specific platform requirement so that it won't hinder to detect the installable set of packages.